# calling a UINavigationController from a MapViewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a MapViewController, A UINavigatioController that encapsulates a UITableViewController that segue to a UIViewController all placed in a **storyboard**. on the map I have a button when clicking on it I wish to call the UITableViewController and be able to open the UIViewController.

if I call

```
[self presentViewController:self.tableViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

the TableViewController is shown but when clicking on the disclosure indicator an exception in throw:

> *"Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'showApartmentDetails'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."*

Creating a property of type UINavigationController and initializing it by using

```
self.navigationController = (UINavigationController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNavigationController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tableViewController animated:NO];
```

doesn't do anything!

please advise how can i call the navigator?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of

```
[self presentViewController:self.tableViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

You need to present the `UINavigationController` that handles `tableViewController`. So you need to link that `UINavigationController` from the storyboard to a outlet called `UINavigationController *tableViewNavigationController`, in `MapViewController`.

```
[self presentViewController:self.tableViewNavigationController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

or just add a modal segue from the button in the `MapViewController` to the `UINavigationController` in the storyboard.

Comment: what do you mean tableViewNavigationController what type of property is it? self is mapviewcontroller it doesn't have a presentViewController interface  `No visible @interface for 'MapViewController' declares the selector 'pushViewController:animated:`

Comment: @liva I edited my solution. This property is supposed to be the `UINavigationController` that contains the `tableViewController`.

Comment: to create an outlet i need to create my own class that derives from UINavigationController that does nothing, instead i get the instance with this `self.navigationController = (UINavigationController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNavigationController"];`

Comment: No, You don't need to create a new subclass. **BTW** the segue from the button to the `UINavigationController` is much simpler.

Comment: `self.navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNavigationController"];` will not work, because, in order to **push** another view controller B from view controller A, A must be already **managed and presented** by a `UINavigationController`. So this `UINavigationController` is the one that will actually push B. The mentioned line code will do nothing.